# Circular Import in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, request-response

I have been trying to run a client-server application using Django. When I am trying to run my server in Django , it is giving me the following error.

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '' does not appear to
>    have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

The project urls.py -

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^', include('chat.views')),
]
```

App's views.py -

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
def home(request):
if request.method == 'POST':

    if request.is_ajax():

       //code
        return JsonResponse(data)

return render(request,'index.html')
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @ABDULNIYASPM Trying to include views.py file from my app named 'chat'

Comment: Your code is properly indented in your actual code, right? Might want to fix that on your post. Also can we see your chat views.py?

Comment: @ABDULNIYASPM  Yes i have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`include` method takes app urls.py model not views.py. You need to create `urls.py` file inside your app and replace `url(r'^', include('chat.views'))` with `url(r'^', include('chat.urls'))` in projects urls file. See django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urls/#include).

Comment: Okay I'll try that.

Comment: That helped. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Include method in **url.py** file is used to include url patterns that are specified in other file. and when you are doing this **url(r'^', include('chat.views'))**, it is unable to find  url patterns in your views file. Hence giving error this:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf ''
>   does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns
>   in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

we generally create a urls.py file in our app folder and write all our url patterns regarding this app in this file.
create a new **urls.py** file in your app folder and write url patterns in that file.

and then include your **app's urls.py** file in **main urls.py** file like this:-

`url(r'^', include('chat.urls')),`

and your app's urls.py file should look like:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'', views.home, name = "home")),
]
```

you can find out more about django urls from documentation:- [django urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urls/)

And if you don't want to create new **urls.py** file in you app directory then you can just import your views in **main urls.py** file and write url pattern in this file. then your **main urls.py** file will look like this:-

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from chat.views import home

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', home, name = "home"),
]
```